# German number sequence

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Classical format, here is a sequence of numbers, you need to find out how it continues:

> 5, 4, 14, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, -3, -1, -2, -3, -7, -7, -6

This puzzle should also have the tag 'Germany' although that is not a valid tag for this Stack Exchange. No knowledge of the German language is needed to solve this puzzle.

*Hint 1:*

> The number 5 is really important for this puzzle.

*Hint 2:*

> Solving this is somewhat urgent. If there is no solution by the weekend I will have to adjust all the numbers.

*Hint 3:*

> The sequence and puzzle at it is written now is still valid until Friday evening (German time). I may update the sequence (and the really important number from Hint 1) on Sunday evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence continues with:

> -12

Based on the hints, I was fairly sure the sequence related to

> teams in the German Bundesliga, and the current league standings.

There are 18 of these, and 17 in the given sequence with one missing value to complete.

The urgency is due to the fact that

> The current table is after all teams have played 5 games (hence the importance of that number). The next game in the league will be played on Friday evening, which will affect the standings.

The sequence matches

> The goal difference of the teams in order from the league table, with the last team missing.

Comment: Good job. Feedback for me, all three hints were needed?

Comment: Hint 2 was probably the most important. Hint 1 just confirmed I was on the right track. And hint 3 sort of just combined the other 2. Definitely think hint 2 was needed, I wouldn't have got it otherwise. Even then I initially thought it might somehow be related to politics and a forthcoming election, but there wasn't any.